# How can I have the native iPhone tab bar at the bottom of the screen using Phonegap?

Tags: iphone, html, css, xcode, cordova

How can I have the native iPhone tab bar at the bottom of the screen using Phonegap?

I'm trying to develop the most native looking iPhone application by using phonegap.

Answer (score 1):

Try the NativeControls plugin for iOS

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/NativeControls

Comment: Sorry to bug you but how do I add them to my project? :)

Thanks very much!

Comment: copy the m and h files into the root of your xcode project. copy the js file to the www dir. link the js file from your index.html file. look at the api in the js file and ... profit!